# Php high memory usage

Tags: php, performance, memory-leaks, zend-framework2, composer-php

We have an old facebook app, running smoothly written in native php.

This month we decided to rewrite it in zend-framework 2. Yesterday, after switching to new app it crashed our server with lots of out of memory errors. So we turned back to old app.

I installed xdebug to profile the app. Using memory_get_peak_usage() function i noticed high memory usage.

In the old app, a static page uses only 1 mb memory. But the new one using 7-8 mb approximately on the same page.

Here's the top two rows from webgrind:

```
   Function                                     Invocation Count    Total Self Cost    Total Inclusive Cost
   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass     224                 23.31       47.20
   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile      224                 9.57        10.23
```

Also tried tha apache's ab tool

```
   ab -n 50 -c 5 -C PHPSESSID=SESSIONID http://myhost.com
```

Result is:

```
   Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
   50%    368
   66%    506
   75%    601
   80%    666
   90%   1073
   95%   1812
   98%   2278
   99%   2278
   100%   2278 (longest request)
```

All these results from the production server not localhost.

Is 7-8 mb for a single page normal? If not, how can i reduce it? Should i look for it in zf2 or composer?

I can give code samples if you need. Thank you.

Comment: step through the app with a debugger. at these rates it should be obvious what is being called/instantiated 100 times in a row for no aparent reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a day to figure out problem. Tried xdebug, xhprof. There was no problem in the code.

We switched back to 2.0.0 and problem solved. I don't know what is wrong with new versions, for now stick with the 2.0.0.

Overall memory usage is around 4mb, no crashes.

composer.json:

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.0.0",
```

Answer (score 2):

When you migrate a solution from native to Zend, you must be aware of the way Zend works.

Zend is composed of lot of classes, and the memory used increase while you use Objects instead of native/light structures.

To improve memory use, review your code and do the following :

- wrap some code in functions, it helps Garbage collector to remove unused objects from memory.
- Don't store large lists of object in arrays before printing them, juste print on the fly.
- Limit the creation of objects (calls to 'new') in loops.

Hop this helps.